# How to achieve linear gradient for bar graph in highcharts

Tags: jquery, css, highcharts

I have created a bar charts using highcharts, and for bar fill color need to give lienar gradient. not sure how to set linear gradient. if any one have idea, could you please help me ?

What I expect:

[image]

what i have tried :

```
 $(function () {
    $('#ao-mix-allocation').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            spacingBottom: 0,
            spacingTop: 0,
            spacingLeft: 0,
            spacingRight: 0,
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(0, 5);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            min:0,
            categories: [
                'S1',
                'S2',
                'S3',
                'S4',
                'S5',
                'S6',
                'S7',
                'S8',
                'S9',
                'S10',
                'S11',
                'S12',

            ],
            crosshair: false,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            tickWidth: 0
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 150,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            gridLineWidth: 0,
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true,
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0,
                width: 11,
                //stacking: 'normal',
                //grouping: true
                color: {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#0058a5'],
                        [1, '#3f85c8']
                    ]
                }

            },

        },
        series: AoMixAllocationData()
    });
```

JSFIDDLE is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sarav4gs/nk7zmxpr/1/)

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Try to play around the `linearGradient`. This is my edited [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/nk7zmxpr/2/) which displays two different colors in a bar from top to bottom. Refer to this [API](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors) to get detailed idea of how it works.

Comment: Sure!! plese help me for my other issue if u can? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37314801/markers-circles-in-spline-chart-in-highcharts

Comment: @IamSarav I had answered that question too. Do take a look.